# Fastest/simplest/shortest/easiest way to check WiFi WPS enabled? Command line if possible - Different platforms

Tags: wireless-networking, command-line, wps

I would like to make a list of the simplest/fastest way to check if a WiFi network has WPS enabled. Until now, this is the compilation:

1. Windows:

   - GUI:      [Don't know]
   - Command line:         [Don't know.
     There are commands for WiFi management in Windows Vista and above,
     but I think they don't deal with WPS]
2. Linux:

   - GUI:
     [Don't know]
   - Command line:

     - wash (included in [Reaver WPS](http://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/))    -->  not working OK with several NICs.
     - [EAPScan](https://code.google.com/p/eapeak/): "eapscan -i mon0 -b aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff -e MyWiFiAP --check-wps" (network by network, once each time :-( ).
3. Android:

   - GUI:

     - Android Setup --> WiFi Networks       --> Fantastic. Simple and working fine.
     - [InSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) (not free since v4)         --> Very good, too.
   - Command line:

     - wpa_cli       --> Try to connect using "wps_reg xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 12345678". A stupid method.

I will edit this post to add the best/acceptable results (if we find them ;-) ).

· Edit: Added new method for Linux CLI: EAPScan from EAPeak Suite.

Comment: Andre Gasser's blog entry has a way to use wireshark to filter by WPS state: http://blog.andregasser.net/?p=243 Not sure if the approach would work under Windows, but might be another tool/way to do what you're looking to do.

Comment: Indeed, this wireshark filter reveals that WPS is enabled: "wps.wifi_protected_setup_state == 2". I am not very experienced at bash scripts: would it be possible to make a simple program/script that captures live WiFi network traffic and shows (only once per ESSID/BSSID) the network name (ESSID/BSSID) of the corresponding packet?I don't know if this is what Wash (Reaver for Linux) does, but as long as we don't have better solutions, we could use it as a generic method. It could even work on Windows or Android.

Comment: It should work in Windows or whichever platform Wireshark supports, as long as there's a driver to put the NIC into "promiscuous" mode. Wish I could help you with the bash script, but it has been a while. But if you're OK with it, I could make the comment into an answer. :-)

Comment: No problem for me. Maybe then someone more expertised will help us with the script for a live identification of WPS capable networks. A possible way could be the request of some parsing of data from airodump-ng (live capture or file dump). Or asking about the possibility of using EAPScan, even when it seems to work in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

Kali-Linux:
wash -i mon0
or
wash -i mon0 -C

Comment: As mentioned in my initial post: "not working OK with several NICs".